# RestKit Object Mapping With Odd JSON

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, restkit

Hi I'm trying to object map the following JSON:

```
{    
"0":{       
       "chapter":"four",       
       "book":"Time Machine"    
    },    
"1":{       
      "chapter":"nine",       
      "book":"Science"    
    },    
"2":{       
      "chapter":"one",       
      "book":"Fiction Man"    
    },    
"3":{       
      "chapter":"25",       
      "book":"Cars"    
    } 
}
```

Code I am using:

```
RKObjectMapping *bookMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Book class]];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider addObjectMapping:bookMapping];

[retailerMapping mapKeyPathsToAttributes:@"chapter", @"chapter",@"book", @"book", nil];
[objectManager.mappingProvider setMapping:bookMapping forKeyPath:@"0"];
```

This works for the first set, but will obviously skips 1, 2, and 3. How can I make this work?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you have control over the structure of the JSON change it to be an array in place of a dictionary. Otherwise you may try mapKeyPath to key.attribute, for example 0.chapter

Example of JSON:

```
{chapters:[    
   {       
   "chapter":"four",       
   "book":"Time Machine"    
   },    
  {       
  "chapter":"nine",       
  "book":"Science"    
  },    
  {       
  "chapter":"one",       
  "book":"Fiction Man"    
  },    
  {       
  "chapter":"25",       
  "book":"Cars"    
  }
 ] 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately I don't have control of the JSON. Won't 0.chapter lead to the same problem? That is, I will be able to get 0.chapter but won't be able to get say 20.chapter unless I explicitly call it out. It's that number index that is making it difficult.

Comment: You can look at RKDynamicObjectMapping, but i do think you may need to iterate over keys to create these objects as there is no way to know what the keys will be with this structure of JSON

Comment: Thanks user1760726, I did as you suggested. That is, basically creating a mapping for multiple key paths.